# How to get JSON object from Razor Model object in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In viewmodel object, below is the property:

```
  public IList<CollegeInformationDTO> CollegeInformationlist { get; set; }
```

In VIEW, javascript is as follow:

```
   var obj = JSON.stringify('@Model.CollegeInformationlist');
   alert(obj[1].State);  //NOT WORKING, giving string char

      $.each('@Model.CollegeInformationlist', function (i, item) {
    var obj = JSON.stringify(item);
    var r = $.parseJSON(obj);
    alert(r.State);    //just giving undefined.
    });
```

Please guide here, how i can get JSON object in javascript.

Comment: your javascript doesn't know what your CollegeInformationDTO class looks like.  At my last job we defined an object in the script with the same structure as the model and then did a jquery .map to map the model to the javascript object.  Also make sure what you are passing to the view is a JSON string

Comment: You need to serialise your Model object to JSON. You should create a method (or property) that returns that result.

Comment: Can you please share me some stuff to do this. here, i wrote `var obj = JSON.stringify('@Model.CollegeInformationlist');` so, it should convert to JSON object and able to give result when explicitly write `.State` property but, its not working like a way. It looks, OBJECT is converted to string type.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.CollegeInformationlist));
```

This would output the following (without seeing your model I've only included one field):

```
<script>
    var json = [{"State":"a state"}];   
</script>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/roZhdj)

**AspNetCore**

AspNetCore uses `Json.Serialize` intead of `Json.Encode`

```
var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model.CollegeInformationlist));
```

**MVC 5/6**

You can use Newtonsoft for this:

```
    @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, 
Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented))
```

This gives you more control of the json formatting i.e. indenting as above, camelcasing etc.

Comment: I could not find JSON reference, getting an error as `The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context
` If i add, `Newtonsoft.Json.` then, `Encode` not found.

Comment: @dhaval http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: For anyone using AspNetCore, that uses `Json.Serialize` instead of `Json.Encode`.

Comment: For newer versions of MVC 5/6 
`@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented))`

Comment: @R2D2 an added spin on your suggestion: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() })` this also insures proper JavaScript CamelCase (or I should say `camelCase`) for the serialized JSON.

Comment: @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, 
Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)) worked for me

Comment: If the json object contains string values that contain html markup inside them, this will break the page.

Comment: A solution that is safe for XSS attacks?

Comment: XSS attacks solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor

Comment: @Marius98 The MVC 5/6  Newtonsoft example above. The XSS risk is increased if the model that is eventually serialized has came from the client or an external source too.

Comment: Note for potential readers, you need to include a using statement for both Newtonsoft.Json and Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject(); (for MVC5+)

Answer (score 22):

In ASP.NET Core the [IJsonHelper.Serialize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ijsonhelper.serialize?view=aspnetcore-2.0) returns `IHtmlContent` so you don't need to wrap it with a call to `Html.Raw()`.

It should be as simple as:

```
<script>
  var json = @Json.Serialize(Model.CollegeInformationlist);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

After use code`var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.CollegeInformationlist));`

You need use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))`;

Comment: Small thing but you should format your code segment on the second line. It's too small of an edit so it won't let me do it.

Comment: Why would you `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` right one after another? It wouldn't be needed and would waste the resources.

Comment: Make sense. I need test if work without JSON.stringify. I think that just `JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.CollegeInformationlist)))` should work.
Someone can test and let us know.
But now I use that way and work to me.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the object from controller to view, convert it to markup without encoding, and parse it to json.

```
@model IEnumerable<CollegeInformationDTO>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
          var jsArray = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model))');
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Why would you wrap the result in quotes and `JSON.parse` right one after another? It wouldn't be needed and would waste the resources.

Answer (score 1):

If You want make json object from yor model do like this :

```
  foreach (var item in Persons)
   {
    var jsonObj=["FirstName":"@item.FirstName"]
   }
```

Or Use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to make json from your model :

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me

```
var chartD =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([@Json.Serialize(@Model)]));
```