# How to avoid double encoding of raw JSON output by a view

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm getting the following JavaScript error when trying to parse JSON that I'm getting from my controller:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1 at
>   JSON.parse () at stores:76

Here is the code that serializes my list of elements (so i can send it to frontend as string then parse it with `JSON.parse()`)

```
FeatureCollection mapFeatureCollection = new FeatureCollection(mapFeatures); // this is my object

// FeatureCollection instances provides the method ToJson which converts them to Json strings, use it before sending the FeatureCollection to the frontend
string nearbyStoresAsGeoJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mapFeatureCollection, Formatting.Indented);

// pass the json to view to mark them
ViewBag.nearbyStores = nearbyStoresAsGeoJSON;
return View("Stores");
```

Now I think where the problem lies is when i get the JSON in the frontend and I log it to the console, this is what i see:

```
{&#xA;  &quot;type&quot;: &quot;FeatureCollection&quot;,&#xA;  &quot;features&quot;: [&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.6350367,&#xA;          33.5841643&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;Bigstone, 48 Rue Abou Salt Andaloussi, Casablanca 20250, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    },&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.631687,&#xA;          33.584392&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;Rue Ibnou Al Arif, Casablanca, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    },&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.636013,&#xA;          33.5838827&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;62 Rue Abou Ishak Al Marouni, Maarif, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    },&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.635459,&#xA;          33.584367&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;79 Rue Abou Salt Andaloussi, Casablanca 20300, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    },&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.6336024,&#xA;          33.5834623&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;33 Rue Ahmed Barakat, Casablanca 20250, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    },&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.633257,&#xA;          33.583944&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;39 Rue Ahmed Barakat, Casablanca 20000, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    },&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.631826,&#xA;          33.5845488&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;10 Rue Ibnou Al Arif, Casablanca 20330, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    },&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.6334731,&#xA;          33.5834792&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;Rue Ahmed Barakat, Casablanca, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    },&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.6393279,&#xA;          33.5791312&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;Rue Al Fourate, Casablanca, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    },&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.634933,&#xA;          33.58392&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;51 Ma&#xE2;rif Rue Abou Salt Andaloussi, Casablanca 20000, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    },&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.6357673,&#xA;          33.5820976&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;14 Rue Ibnou Nafiss, Maarif, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    },&#xA;    {&#xA;      &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,&#xA;      &quot;geometry&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,&#xA;        &quot;coordinates&quot;: [&#xA;          -7.6367801,&#xA;          33.5830291&#xA;        ]&#xA;      },&#xA;      &quot;properties&quot;: {&#xA;        &quot;address&quot;: &quot;146 Rue Abou Zaid Addadoussi, Casablanca 20330, Morocco&quot;&#xA;      }&#xA;    }&#xA;  ]&#xA;}
```

Comment: what is the result if you remove the `, Formatting.Indented`?

Comment: It's double encoding your json so that it could for example be displayed as html. Show how you output it in your view. My bet is you're doinv something like `@ViewBag.nearbyStores` which is going to cause it to be encoded with html entities

Comment: [there is no such thing as a json object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Daniel same result

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 like this `var stores = '@ViewBag.nearbyStores';
      var geojson = JSON.parse(stores);`

Comment: Use `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.nearbyStores)`. Otherwise it will run through the encoder. Or use  `@Json.Serialize`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get JSON object from Razor Model object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344089/how-to-get-json-object-from-razor-model-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks dude, `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.nearbyStores)` did it, again thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end up double-escaping/encoding the JSON. The Razor Helper `@` under *most* circumstances is going to try and encode the input and return HTML entities for things like quotes, ampersands, less/greater signs etc.

You can use the [`@Html.Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.raw?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method to indicate that the input is *already* an encoded string.

```
var stores = '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.nearbyStores)';
var geojson = JSON.parse(stores);
```

But note I'd be careful. You never know what might be in the source variable that could cause some sort of injection attack (an unescaped single quote for example).

You *should* be able to avoid the extra parsing altogether:

```
var stores = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.nearbyStores);
```

But that's with the understanding the `nearbyStores` is in fact valid JSON.

Rather than serializing in your controller, you could make this the responsibility of the view using [JsonHelper.Serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.jsonhelper.serialize?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
//controller 
ViewBag.nearbyStores = mapFeatureCollection;
// view
var stores = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.nearbyStores));
```

Comment: Or better yet, you could just use `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.nearbyStores)` and no further parsing needs to be done.