# How to access c# model data in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

New to ASP.NET MVC 3. Started with a tutorial and am mirroring the code for my own model. I Can access the model data in my Index.cshtml file in the script but not in my javascript functions.

My Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DotNetCoreSqlDb.Models

{
    public class Glassblower
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string TeacherID { get; set; }
        public string Lat { get; set; }
        public string Lng { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Coe { get; set; }
        public string SubscriptionLevel { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My controller Index method:

```
// GET: Glassblowers
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Glassblower.ToListAsync());
        }
```

My Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<DotNetCoreSqlDb.Models.Glassblower>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<script id="gmapsrc" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBSJAns0GMR5gK60kw2c3IAnouZpyu_QHw"
></script>



<div class="row map-and-readout-container">
     <div id="timescale-map" class="timescale-map"></div>
    <div id="readout" class="readout">

       @foreach (var item in Model) {
               <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
               </div>
        }
    </div>

</div>
<script>
 var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model));
</script>
```

Currently I am able to render the item names on the page. My goal is to loop through the model in a javascript function in my  tag.

I've tried accessing it with

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model))
```

but when I click run in Visual Studio Mac I get this build error

```
'IJsonHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Encode' and no accessible extension method 'Encode' accepting a first argument of type 'IJsonHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (DotNetCoreSqlDb)
```

Any Tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's beacause your models is not json, you can try to put it in a **array** or **list** like this.

```
<script>
    var availableTags = [];
    @foreach(var model in Model.Model)
    {
        @:availableTags.push(decodeHtml("@model"));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I got most of it to work with var m in Model etc. said I couldn't call @model twice. But then I get a decodeHtml is not defined error

Comment: Have you try to get your list with Ajax?

Comment: So you can make a function in your controller to return only json when call with Ajax,

Comment: Just found this for you! : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344334/9231356

Comment: Thanks Dannick after looking at that I found I needed Serialize instead of Encode  var m = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model));