# Validate credit card using Stripe

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, credit-card, stripe.net

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and am using `Stripe.net`.

Here is the code that is used to validate a credit card using `Javascript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function () {
        Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_****');

        var isValid = Stripe.card.valid("4242 4242 4242 4242");
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way to do this using C# code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest against having credit card information going back to your server (unless you absolutely have to).

One you get have that data travelling back to your server you enter the world of [PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/merchants/how_to_be_compliant.php) - there's a lot of work to do and if you get it wrong you could be subject to some HUGE fines!

Instead (personally), I'd use Stripe's javascript to perform any checks involving sensitive data (as it keeps it away from your servers)

[Stripe is PCI compliant - Level 1](https://support.stripe.com/questions/is-stripe-pci-compliant) (the most stringent of checks)

So I'd feel safe using them, then by using their javascripts they make it easy for [you to also be PCI compliant](https://support.stripe.com/questions/do-i-need-to-be-pci-compliant-what-do-i-have-to-do)

Summary from the link above:

- communicate over SSL/TLS
- use the stripe javascript files

They also go on to mention that they will help you ensure you are PCI compliant once you start accepting payments.

For me it'd be a no brainer - ensure stripe do all the hard work and keep load/sensitive payment data away from my server!!

If however you need credit card data going back to your server, then I'd create a thin WebApi controller with a Validate(GET) method with car number parameter in the querystring, returning the validity of that card number.

For the actual nitty-gritty C# code I'd use the [Stripe library the guys from ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Stripe) have created and actively use on the Stack* sites

Comment: Is the "Stripe library the guys from ServiceStack" PCI compliant?

Comment: The library isn't the thing that needs to be compliant. The compliance is all about what YOU do with the data, if you're storing it securely etc. As soon as this sensitive data hits your servers YOU have to ensure YOU are PCI compliant

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with c# code, you have to do a full site post back or you can call your controller with jQuery asynchrone. In any case you need to implement the card-validation logic in c# first. I would prefer wirting a `Controller` and access it via jQuery.

What you need is:

1. Input and Output model
2. Controller
3. JavaScript/jQuery implementation in your view.

Take a look at this nice SO-Article: [How to get data from ASP.NET MVC controller to jQuery dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13201471/2630261)