# how to use jquery post method in asp.net mvc 5 in host?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, plesk

i use jquery post method in site. it's work in localhost but not work in Host.

```
 $.post('/Home/GetCityLists', null, function (data) {
    var Data = JSON.parse(data);
    for (item of Data) {
        CitiesList.push({ label: item.CityName, value: item.CityId, desc: item.StateName })
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string GetCityLists()
    {
        return ConvertToJson(RunSp("MainDB", "Data", "uspGetCitys").Tables["tblCitys"]);
    }
```

Error in host:

[image]
POST mysite.com/Home/GetCityLists 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: A 500 error means the problem occurred on the server, it's not a JS issue. Given that the problem only appears on your production server it's likely to be a configuration problem. Check your logs for the error and diagnose from there

Comment: Can you add `try-catch` block and see what's the exception `Internal Server Error` throws?

Comment: Seems this is not the error of jquery, this from server side

Comment: need to run app or plugin in host?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data from ASP.NET MVC controller to jQuery dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198136/how-to-get-data-from-asp-net-mvc-controller-to-jquery-dynamically)